# Magento 1.x - Custom JS/CSS not found

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, javascript, css, 404-page

I added these custom js and css file:

1. `skin/frontend/base/default/black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js`
2. `skin/frontend/base/default/black/NewsletterPopup/css/main.js`

Then I included them via my modules layout file

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/black/newsletter_popup.phtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>black/NewsletterPopup/css/main.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
<!-- ... -->
```

But a network analysis showed that the files could not be found and if I enter the link to the file directly into the URL then the "*404 Sorry page not found*" page shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
<action method="addJs">
    <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js</script>
</action>
```

which actually targets the `{magentoroot}/js` folder, to

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js</script>
</action>
```

which targets the skin folder.

Comment: yes, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                  <type>skin_js</type>
                  <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                 <type>skin_css</type>
                  <name>black/NewsletterPopup/css/main.css</name> 
                 <params/>
             </action>

        </reference>
    </default>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: This is just a copy from my answer.? Or not?

Comment: No, I have not copy your answer, I just check in Magento 1.9.3. I have added for CSS also. Even take time to format my answer.

Comment: It is not needed for CSS though, I tried it and it also works with `addCss` somehow.

Comment: You can add `media="all"` extra param by `skin_css` `public function addItem($type, $name, $params=null, $if=null, $cond=null)
    {
        if ($type==='skin_css' && empty($params)) {
            $params = 'media="all"';
        }
        $this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name] = array(
            'type'   => $type,
            'name'   => $name,
            'params' => $params,
            'if'     => $if,
            'cond'   => $cond,
       );
        return $this;
    }`

Answer (score -1):

Your layout file should be a .xml file and not .phtml file :

(app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/black/newsletter_popup.***phtml***)

Comment: Thats incorrect.