# Magento 1.8 - How to addItem to block other than `head`?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, javascript, css

I successfully added some custom JS and CSS to my head section ([look here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228531/magento-1-x-custom-js-css-not-found)).

But If I try to add a script at the block `before_body_end` then I get:

> ```
> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Text_List::addItem(Array
> (
>     [0] => skin_js
>     [1] => black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js
> )
> ```

**app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\black\newsletter_popup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js</script>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>black/NewsletterPopup/css/magnific-popup.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>black/NewsletterPopup/css/main.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>black/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: because `addItem` method not exist `core/text_list` you can call your custom modules block there.

Comment: Ok I see, `addItem` is not supported for blocks with type `core/text_list` for whatever reason. I can call my modules block which includes html., But how can I properly include my script?

Comment: your way is proper to include JS file. you can access js functions in your  block which you added under `before_body_end`.

Comment: Ok I see, so I could just add a `<script></script>` block to the template with the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing my layout file to:

```
<layout>
    <!-- ... --->
    <default>
        <!-- ... --->
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/text" name="newsletterpopup_main.js">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/base/default/fekete/NewsletterPopup/js/main.js"></script>]]></text>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <!-- ... --->
    </default>
    <!-- ... --->
</layout>
```

I found the answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55377/trouble-adding-js-to-before-body-end-without-modifying-magento-theme).